# How to use a custom SSO in my other apps?

Tags: c#, .net, authentication, jwt

I hit a wall trying to use a custom SSO in my apps so I figured I'd take a step back and ask questions here.

I implemented a RESTful Authentication API in .Net 5.0 (without `Identity`) by following [this article](https://dev.to/moe23/asp-net-core-5-rest-api-authentication-with-jwt-step-by-step-140d).
I can call `http://localhost:4001/api/auth/login` with an email and a password to get a JWT in response

```
{
    "token": "eyJhb<--removed jwt-->",
    "errors": null
}
```

- Is this a good approach? I didn't want to use something as bulky as `Identity` or as complicated as or `OAuth`.
- How do I tie this up with a normal authentication "flow"? I know that you have to `Challenge` the identity provider while logging in, but I couldn't find any exemples on how to do it that would fit my situation. (Itried to implement a custom scheme with `builder.AddJwtBearer("my_scheme", ...` but this is where I hit a wall)

Comment: You should not post real token online (not sure if yours is).

Comment: It's just test data, nothing risky but thank ;)

Comment: This would almost work. Two issues. First, all your client apps have to post username/password to the auth endpoint. This is bad design, your users won't repeat their credentials in each app. Second, to post username/password a client app has to collect it. This is bad, users have to trust apps they don't know. Enterprise SSO flows like SAML or OpenID solve these problems. Instead of designing your own solution, just implement one of the two. OpenId is simpler, you could even do it "by hand"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do what I wanted, so if anyone stumbles upon this:

Turns out that I was making this out to be super complicated when it's actually quite simple...
The point was to make things easy, so trying to create en authentication scheme was off topic.
Here is the final code:

```
        using var client = new HttpClient() { BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:4001/api/") };
        try
        {
            var stringContent = new StringContent(JsonSerializer.Serialize(new { email = model.Email, password = model.Password }), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            var result = await client.PostAsync("auth/login", stringContent);

            var jsonResponse = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            var options = new JsonSerializerOptions { PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true };
            var authResult = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<AuthResult>(jsonResponse, options);

            var jwt = authResult.Token.Jwt;
            var isValidJwt = JwtHelper.ValidateCurrentToken(jwt, _myExternalAuthSettings.RsaPub, _myExternalAuthSettings.Issuer);

            if (isValidJwt)
            {
                HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Append("my_auth", jwt, new CookieOptions()
                {
                    Domain = "localhost",
                    Expires = DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeSeconds(authResult.Token.UnixTimeExpiresAt)
                });
                // finish authenticating the user
            }
            // something failed
        }
```

Note: I followed [this article](https://medium.com/dev-genius/jwt-authentication-in-asp-net-core-e67dca9ae3e8) to be able to locally validate the token with the public key (the private key is used to create it).

Cheers

Comment: Note that this is not SSO. As the name implies, sso requires a **single** sign on. In your approach each client app is supposed to ask for the email/password pair.

Comment: True this is not a SSO. I called it that because I wasn't sure how to call it.

Comment: No problem. I am not criticizing your answer nor down voting  but leaving a comment for future readers that would be confused otherwise.